# EPPlus, Find and set the value for a Named Range

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I've been pulling my hair out trying to set the value of a named range (in this case, a single named cell) using the ExcelPackage (3.0.1) library, it should be a simple as this:

```
ExcelNamedRange er = xlPackage.Workbook.Names["Customer"];
er.Value = "Foo Bar";
```

I'm obviously doing it wrong - has anyone got an example I can follow

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

I looked for ExcelPackage documentation to see what type Names[] collection returns and found that documentatios will come soon, or at least that is what they said back in 2007.

I suggest you use EPPlus wich is a excel library (xlsx only) that have worked great to me.

[official link](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)

Now, to set a value for each cell in a named range:

```
ExcelWorksheet sheet = _openXmlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets["SheetName"];
using (ExcelNamedRange namedRange = sheet.Names["RangeName"])
{
    for (int rowIndex = Start.Row; rowIndex <= namedRange.End.Row; rowIndex++)
    {
        for (int columnIndex = namedRange.Start.Column; columnIndex <= namedRange.End.Column; columnIndex++)
        {
            sheet.Cells[rowIndex, columnIndex].Value = "no more hair pulling";                        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My range is a single cell. The above code claims namedRange.Start.Row is -1.

Comment: It should work for a single cell, but I'm not 100% sure. I see you managed to solve your problem, glad you did. I'm leaving my answer here in case someone with Named Ranges issues is interested on trying EPPlus instead. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

I had to put in a work around using a cell value instead.

```
using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
            {
                foreach (ExcelWorksheet worksheet in xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets)
                {

                    var dimension = worksheet.Dimension;
                    if (dimension == null) { continue; }
                    var cells = from row in Enumerable.Range(dimension.Start.Row, dimension.End.Row)
                                from column in Enumerable.Range(dimension.Start.Column, dimension.End.Column)
                                //where worksheet.Cells[row, column].Value.ToString() != String.Empty
                                select worksheet.Cells[row, column];
                    try
                    {
                        foreach (var excelCell in cells)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                if (excelCell.Value.ToString().Equals("[Customer]")) { excelCell.Value = "Customer Name"; }

                            }
                            catch (Exception) { }
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception a) { Console.WriteLine(a.Message); }
                }
```

Comment: Is this to set the range that you will search though? so that you don't search though empty cells? I need something like this?