# How to set value of Excel cell by name instead of using coordinates with EPPlus?

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, epplus, excelpackage

I am able to set cell values using EPPlus:

```
var template = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/my_template.xlsx"));
var pck = new ExcelPackage(template);
var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
ws.Cells[15, 4].Value = 66; 
ws.Cells["B1"].Value = 55;
```

Instead of addressing the target cell by its coordinates I would like
to use a named cell/variable "profits".

```
ws.Range("profits").Value = 66;
```

However, EPPlus does not support ws.Range(...).

=> Is it nevertheless possible to do so? How would I write an extension method that provides the wanted functionality?

Related articles/questions:

a) Doc for EPPlus:

http://epplus.codeplex.com

b) How to use named cells/variables in Excel:

https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000704.htm

[What's the RIGHT way to reference named cells in Excel 2013 VBA? (I know I'm messing this up)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228318/whats-the-right-way-to-reference-named-cells-in-excel-2013-vba-i-know-im-mes)

c) Libraries for creating Excel Files with C#

[Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var profits = pck.Workbook.Names["profits"];
profits.Value = 66;
```

from

[Is there a way to get 'named' cells using EPPlus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494913/is-there-a-way-to-get-named-cells-using-epplus)

It is also possible to set the values for a named range:

```
var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
using (var namedRange = pck.Workbook.Names["MyNamedRange"])
      {
        for (int rowIndex = namedRange.Start.Row; rowIndex <= namedRange.End.Row; rowIndex++)
        {
          for (int columnIndex = namedRange.Start.Column; columnIndex <= namedRange.End.Column; columnIndex++)
          {
            ws.Cells[rowIndex, columnIndex].Value = 66;
          }
        }
      }
```

from

[EPPlus, Find and set the value for a Named Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11332326/epplus-find-and-set-the-value-for-a-named-range)